# ACCESS SQL: TOP 1 of a subcategory (or MAX())

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

If the question doesn't seem very clear, it should be after this explanation !

Here is my table: Flights (AC, hours, cycles, flight_date)
ac = aicraft
hours = total aircraft hours
cycles = total aircraft cycles (cycle = flight)
flight_date = self explanatory :)

I'm trying to write a query that will give me the number of hours/cycles all AC have reached on a specific date.
(Keep in mind aircrafts can make a few flights a day, or no flight at all)

Here is what I wrote:

```
SELECT ac, hours, max(cycles)
FROM flights
WHERE flight_date <= cdate(asked_date)  //so access asks me for the date when I run the query
GROUP BY ac, hours
```

but for some reason, this doesn't work:

It returns all the flights from all the aircraft where flight_date <= asked_date (looks like the MAX isn't taken into account at all).

I considered using TOP 1 with a subquery but couldn't find how to do it.
I'm using max(cycles) since if the cycle length is < 1h, we can get records with the same hours, but the cycles will still be different by definition.

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to put max also around the hours column and group only by ac:

```
SELECT ac, max(hours), max(cycles)
FROM flights
WHERE flight_date <= cdate(asked_date)
GROUP BY ac
```

Reason:
As the hours column contains the total hours of the aircraft, grouping by this value, will return you (nearly) all rows, because the value is different in each row. It will only group this rows that have the same value of total hours for a specific aircraft.

Comment: @Daniel you should include a note in your answer that the record with the max(hours) may not be the same as the record the max(cycles) but it will work with the table design since it looks like hours is a rolling sum.

Comment: @Conrad Frix: they will be the same, unless we have 2 same number of hours for the same number of cycles

Comment: @Conrad: Your comment is that note, although this only is a theoretical problem. If the data in that table is consistent, it doesn't matter.

Comment: @Christian: What do you mean with "why is it so"?

Comment: @Daniel I agree that it doesn't matter, and if you want my comment to be the note that's fine with me.

Comment: @Daniel Well, in my case if I end up with, for any ac, the record with the highest cycles, it is also the record with the highest number of hours. So, I don't understand why I need to use max(hours) and can't put hours in the group by clause: this doesn't work... and I don't know why. how is that explained ?

Comment: I already explained this in my answer. GROUP BY groups all rows together into one with the same values in **ALL** the columns specified in the GROUP BY clause, i.e. it groups together all rows that have the same AC *and* the same value in hours. As hours is a running total, there will be (nearly) no two rows that have the same value in the hours column for any given AC.

Comment: @Daniel Somehow I missed your explanation in the answer, my bad. But, if I put hours in the group by, shouldn't it output 1 line per ac anyway, since there is only 1 max(cycles) ?

Comment: @Christian: You really should read up on how GROUP BY works and the order of how stuff is executed. First, the WHERE clause is executed to filter the result to match your condition. Then the result is grouped according to the group by clause and finally, for each group of rows, the maximum cycles value is determined.

Comment: @Daniel well that clears it up. Thanks :) I'll try finding some more info about how sql works in the background.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the hours from both select and group by:

```
SELECT ac, max(cycles) 
FROM flights 
WHERE flight_date <= cdate(asked_date)   
GROUP BY ac
```

if you really need the matching hours of the cycle then:

```
SELECT x.ac, x.cycles, hours
FROM flights 
inner join 
(SELECT ac, max(cycles) as cycles
FROM flights 
WHERE flight_date <= cdate(asked_date)  
GROUP BY ac) x 
on x.ac=flights.ac and x.cycles=flights.cycles
```